# Оптимизиация копирования ячеек массива в случае если де факто копируется в саму себя

Tags: c#

На примере тривиального алгоритма удаления определённого числа из массива:

```
public int RemoveElement(int[] nums, int target)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < nums.Length; j++)
    {
        if (nums[j] != target)
        {
            nums[i] = nums[j];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

var nums = new[] {1,2,3,4,5};
var target = 3;
var newsize = RemoveElement(nums, target);
for (int i = 0; i < newsize; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nums[i]);
}
```

Меня интересует поведение в случае если массив не содержит искомое число: в этом случае i = j и по факту происходит копирование ячейки массива в саму себя. (Аналогично в примере это происходит до момента нахождения тройки)

Есть ли какие-либо оптимизации на уровне ниже C# - т.е. будет ли процессор переписывать ячейку саму в себя или есть какие-либо оптимизиации?

Иначе, если подобных оптимизаций нет, то есть ли смысл делать предварительную проверку на равенство i и j чтобы не выполнять лишний раз перезапись ячеек массива? (Неявно здесь ещё один вопрос: какая операция более дорогая - сравнение i и j или операция записи ячеек? Подозреваю, что вторая, на уровне C и ассемблера по крайней мере, в стековых машинах непонятно, но по идее должно быть так же)

Comment: В последние годы разработчики .NET Core наконец-то занялись оптимизациями рантайма. В новых версиях языка и среды исполнения появляются всё новые оптимизации. И поэтому нельзя уверенно сказать, что и как будет соптимизировано. Нужно рассматривать конкретные версии.

Comment: Вообще, сравнение двух чисел хоть и дёшево, но не бесплатно. Есть такая методика оптимизации: [Sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) - в ней избавляются от одной проверки (из двух) на каждой итерации цикла. И это стоит свеч на длинных массивах.

Comment: @aepot, ну зачем вы удалили? :( Прочитали бы про branch prediction unit и добавили бы тестов. Мне было интересно, что выйдет в результате, ибо на вопрос "дороже ли в среднем ошибка предсказателя переходов, чем лишнее копирование" у меня нет ответа...

Comment: Очень кратко: нет там никакой такой оптимизации копирования ячейки в саму себя. `mov ebx, [edx+esi*4+8]` = прочитали, `cmp ecx, edi; jae short (throw ArgumentOutOfRange)` = сделали баунд-чек, `mov [edx+ecx*4+8], ebx` = записали. Никаких дополнительных проверок того, что оно пишется туда же, откуда оно прочиталось, нет.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov так напишите свой ответ, репрезентативный. Не вижу никаких проблем.

Comment: @aepot, не обижайтесь, пожалуйста, а то чувствую я в вашем комментарии, что вы раздосадованы. У вас был хороший метод, и на упорядоченных данных он отработает в целом лучше, чем метод AK (что вы дополнительно показали и тестом), но из-за ветвления не очень ясно, что будет с примерами "из реального мира", как ваш метод поведёт себя на хаотических данных, где предсказатель будет спотыкаться через шаг, на что я и указал. А сам я ответы не пишу уже давно, принципиально (долгая история, из-за которой уходил VladD и уйдёт снова, но уже окончательно, когда добьёт 200к), только в комментариях сижу

Comment: @Kir_Antipov `т.е. будет ли процессор переписывать ячейку саму в себя` - будет. Вот и весь ответ на вопрос. _branch prediction unit_ здесь вообще не рядом и никаким боком.

Comment: @aepot, ну так это одна часть вопроса. После этого AK спрашивает: "Если подобных оптимизаций нет, то есть ли смысл [сделать ее самому]" - и вот на этот вопрос вы как раз и пытались ответить, и вот тут как раз предсказатель играет весомую роль